# What does “check it out” means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am in a library and the librarian is asking me if I want to check this book out? The book is on my table. Is this some common expression check something out = investigate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People check books out of libraries, meaning the library records their library-card number and issues them a date by which the book is due back.

> [**check out**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/check+out)
>   2. To withdraw (an item) after recording the withdrawal: *check out books*.

(TFD Online)